# GETDATE() specified for field default but not in effect when I pass null to it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Given TSQL**

```
insert into Tasks
select null as userid, 'Test Task 100' as Name, '' as Description, null as DateStarted, null as DateCompleted, null as DateModified
```

The DateStarted field has a default of (getdate()) but it's still null when I execute the preceding TSQL. Any thoughts?

Comment: Isn't there a way to automatically get date created and/or date modified for table rows?

Comment: if you insert something against a field if allowed will insert the data, the default value will kick off then you don't include them from the insert statement

Comment: You are inserting a value of null.

Comment: You need to specify the column names.

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the column name, the server will use the default value.

If you must supply column name, for instance from an ORM or whatever, then you can use the keyword

> DEFAULT

**Reference:**
[INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql)

> **DEFAULT** Forces the Database Engine to load the default value defined
>   for a column. If a default does not exist for the column and the
>   column allows null values, NULL is inserted. For a column defined with
>   the timestamp data type, the next timestamp value is inserted. DEFAULT
>   is not valid for an identity column.

This first statement will allow the server to use the default (by omitting the DateStarted column). Incidentally, you should standardize the case of your column names, and ideally stop using reserved words for column names. It's very annoying to maintenance personnel to see a random mix of "userid", "[Name]" and so on.

```
INSERT INTO
    Tasks
    (
    userid,
    , [Name]
    , [Description]
    , DateCompleted
    , DateModified
    )
VALUES
    (
    NULL --userid
    , 'Test Task 100' --[Name]
    , '' --[Description]
    , NULL --DateCompleted
    , NULL --DateModified
    )
```

This next statement will employ the `DEFAULT` keyword, if you want to be explicit, or if your framework demands the inclusion of the column for some reason.

```
INSERT INTO
    Tasks
    (
    userid,
    , [Name]
    , [Description]
    , DateStarted
    , DateCompleted
    , DateModified
    )
VALUES
    (
    NULL --userid
    , 'Test Task 100' --[Name]
    , '' --[Description]
    , DEFAULT --DateStarted
    , NULL --DateCompleted
    , NULL --DateModified
    )
```